# Can't login to Redmine after fresh install on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, redmine

I did a fresh install of Redmine on Ubuntu 10.04, following the instructions [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_Ubuntu#Ubuntu-1004-and-10041-using-Passenger)

After the installation, I visited `http://localhost/redmine`, and the site came up successfully.  I then registered a user by clicking Register. It seemed successful, but I was unable to login with the user.  In `/etc/redmine/default/database.yml`, it lists a user named `redmine` and a password (that I had entered during the installation) stored in plain text.  I was also unable to login with this account.

Are there any ideas?  Perhaps there is something obvious that I'm missing. Is there a way for me to manually check and see if the users I registered were registered successfully?

**Note** I noticed in the documentation that when registering a user, Redmine is supposed to send an email to the user in order to activate the account.  It's not doing this, which could be the problem.  This still doesn't explain why I can't login with the `redmine` account though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default account information in Redmine is:

username: `admin`

password: `admin`

This account works - my other accounts were failing to login because they had not been activated.  I was able to activate the users by logging in with the `admin` account and going to the Administration page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the standard procedure but you have to log-in as Admin and enable the other accounts you created. User Registration creates an account but will not activate the account.